# Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:jar:0.7.9

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to install and run GrammarViz2 in Ubuntu 18.04 on Oracle virtual machine according to the instruction on https://github.com/GrammarViz2/grammarviz2_src. It requires me to install Java and Maven. I have installed them successfully, but when run

```
$mvn package -PSingle
```

I get the following error. Can any one help me to fix this problem?
Thank you in advance.

```
[INFO] Building GrammarViz2 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jacoco/jacoco-maven-plugin/0.7.9/jacoco-maven-plugin-0.7.9.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.637 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-04-16T14:13:57-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.9 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:jar:0.7.9: Could not transfer artifact org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:pom:0.7.9 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jacoco/jacoco-maven-plugin/0.7.9/jacoco-maven-plugin-0.7.9.pom: Received fatal alert: protocol_version -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

Comment: Are you running on JDK 7 ?

Comment: @khmarbaise yes on java 1.7

Comment: Than you have to give `-Dhttps.protocol=TLSv1.2` cause central is only available via https I strongly recommend to upgrate to JDK8+ ... see also https://blog.sonatype.com/central-repository-moving-to-https also I would suggest to upgrade JaCoCo version to 0.8.5...etc. apart from that the project seemed to be dead?

Comment: For some people on whose computer `-Dhttps.protocol=TLSv1.2` does not work: try `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2`. Putting the `s` at the end so that it's not `-Dhttps.protocol` but `-Dhttps.protocols`. It worked for me.